# MEAN stack app on openshift - force Https connection

Tags: express, https, openshift, mean

People, I have been racking my brain for two days straight, here's my situation:

1. I have a mean stack application running on openshift - all good.
2. I got an SSL certificate and key - all good.
3. I uploaded the certificate and key to openshift and I can access my website over https IF I WRITE IT EXPLICITLY (https://*url.com*)

My problem is - I want to force the user to use Https even if they don't type it in the url bar - I've tried to set up the router so that it redirects insecure requests to https-ed urls, but to no avail (All answers found here on SO) ...

Any input by someone that managed to do this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I resorted to installing [express-sslify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-sslify).

Afterwards, I implemented my version in the following way, because Openshift provides a web load balancer, which is a special case when you want to redirect insecure requests ***(as specified in the documentation of express-sslify!)***

Hopefully this answer helps other people too - solution code below:

```
var enforce = require('express-sslify');

if (config.env === 'production' && config.isStaging === 'false') {

    // Enforce HTTPs connections only
    app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }));

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Just check if "http" is in your the request environment variable and direct manually.   Here is my python code for an example.

```
if request.environ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'http':
Then redirect
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - unfortunately I already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Just curios.  Was the condition caught and the redirect failed or somrthing else?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember any more - I think it resulted in too many redirects, also I have solved this issue, adding an answer now.